# Concatenate multiple mp2 files with constant frame rate 30 results in output with variable frame rate 29.xxx

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I am looking to concatenate multiple `mp4` files (hundreds) that I am generating using `ffmpeg` previously.

I am making sure they have the same codec details and all of them have a constant frame rate of 30FPS.

However, when I concat them using either `demuxer` or `protocol` methods, the result has a lower frame rate (i.e. 29.96).

Investigating using `ffprobe`, looks like the total number of frames match, but the duration is the one that changes.

It is important to be able to do the concatenation without re-encoding as a fast result is needed (all the individual files are created in parallel tasks).

Comment: Check frame rate with ffprobe, not the rounded frame rate shown in ffmpeg: `ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate,avg_frame_rate,time_base input.mp4`

Comment: All of them have the same output:

```[STREAM]
r_frame_rate=30/1
avg_frame_rate=30/1
time_base=1/60
[/STREAM]```

Comment: Same with the output file? How are you determining that the frame rates and durations differ and that the output is VFR?

Comment: Using `mediainfo`. For the output avg_framerate_rate is different.